# Why does the PhpStorm 2017.3.3 (macOS) Command Line Tools Console incorrectly report (and use) my php version

Tags: macos, phpstorm

When running the command `php -v` from various contexts, I get the following output:

**Terminal**

```
PHP 7.1.13 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 15:30:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

**PhpStorm Command Line Tools Console**

```
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2017 20:30:32) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

**The CLI Interpreter settings inside PhpStorm are set correctly**

I have verified the path is correct.

[image]

**The relevant contents of /usr/local/bin**

The command `which php` returns `/usr/local/bin/php`

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 ben   admin    33 17 Jan 15:08 php -> ../Cellar/php71/7.1.13_24/bin/php
lrwxr-xr-x    1 ben   admin    37 17 Jan 15:08 php-cgi -> ../Cellar/php71/7.1.13_24/bin/php-cgi
lrwxr-xr-x    1 ben   admin    40 17 Jan 15:08 php-config -> ../Cellar/php71/7.1.13_24/bin/php-config
```

What might I be missing?

*edit*

**OS path variables**

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/support-files:/usr/local/opt/php71/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/support-files
```

**PhpStorm Command Line Tools Console path variables**

```
echo $SHELL
$SHELL

echo $PATH
$PATH
```

*(not the result I expected from the latter)*

Comment: What is the output of `echo $SHELL` and `echo $PATH` of both Terminal and PHPStorm CLTool? I was experiencing the same, after updating php by `brew`, things worked again.

Comment: @The-VinhVO Please see *edit* above

Comment: @The-VinhVO The shell was/is correctly set to /bin/bash.  No change in output.

Comment: Just for clarity -there is a "Terminal" in PhpStorm *as well as* a "Command Line Tools Console".  The "Terminal" behaves as one would expect.  It is the "Command Line Tools Console with which I am having trouble.

Comment: That obviously explains why you've got $SHELL/$PATH in the output of `echo $SHELL` and `echo $PATH`. I was misunderstanding your trouble. I return to the point above, the built-in php of mac os is a bit outdated, so I had to update it via homebrew, and change using `/usr/local/bin/php` to `/usr/bin/php`. Let me remove some misleading comments above.

Comment: 1) The Command Line Tools Console most likely is not reading the proper PATH variables (your bash/whatever profile). try launching app from terminal and not by clicking on an icon/launcher -- any difference? 2) You better stick to Terminal if you need to run actual commands. Command Line Tools is good for running predefined/supported tools (like Composer or Symfony based console scripts). So you may type `c install` and behind the scene it will execute actual `php composer install`